# Is finite the limit of $(x_n)_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $ (x_n)_n$ and $ (y_n)_n$ two sequences such that $x_1 =1$, $ y_1 =4$  and $ x_{n+1}= \frac{ 4+ 2 x_n + x_n y_n}{y_n}$, $ y_{n+1}= \frac{ 4+ 2 y_n + x_n y_n}{x_n}$. Find the limits of  $ (x_n)_n$ and $ (y_n)_n$. I seen that the sequences are increasing and that the limit of $(y_n)_n$ is infinite. In the same time $ y_n \geq x_n $. I can't to decide if the limit of $(x_n)_n$ is finite or infinite.

Comment: I try with induction or to create new sequences without results.

Comment: Actually calculating the first ~30 values makes it obvious that $x_n \to 4$. I suggest trying to show that $4$ is an upper bound to the sequence. Since $x_n$ is increasing, that shows that it converges. Then show that limit cannot be less than $4$.